# Interview Question

Tags: c++, c

I was asked the output of the following code in my interview yesterday

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
       printf ("%x" ,-1<<4); 
}
```

I was given 2 minutes to tell the answer. I responded `fffffff0`. The result of the interview  has not been declared yet. I want to know was my answer correct?

Comment: Doesn't that depend on the representation of signed integers?

Comment: Well, there's one way to find out.  Compile and run the code, silly!

Comment: @cdhowie - if you're joking, it's funny but probably not fully apparent to the OP.  If you're not, shame on you.

Comment: In addition to the -1<<4 issue, the program has undefined behaviour because there's no return statement in main (this could have practical implications to the "output" question on some platform - can imagine the clean up code that flushes buffers to stdout at the OS level might not get invoked).

Comment: @Tony: `main` doesn't need a return statement. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637671/

Comment: @MSalters: cool - didn't know C99 had added that... (been using C++ too long to care, which clearly means I should be careful with my comments on C code!).  Cheers.

Comment: IIRC even prior to C99, dropping off the end of main was not UB but just resulted in indeterminate exit status.

Comment: @R: I think it wasn't UB to not return, but became UB when the (missing) value was actually used.

Comment: "Well, there's one way to find out. Compile and run the code, silly!" -- The code doing something doesn't tell you whether the spec states the something is undefined or implementation-defined.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Technically left-shifting a negative integer invokes Undefined Behaviour. That means `-1<<4` is UB. I dont know why they asked you this question. Probably they wanted to test your depth of knowledge of the C and C++ Standards.

C99 [`6.5.7/4`] says

> The  result  of E1 << E2 is E1 left-shifted E2 bit  positions;  vacated  bits  are  ﬁlled  with zeros. If E1 has an unsigned type, the value of the result is E1× 2<sup>E2</sup>, reduced modulo
>   one more than the maximum value representable in the result type.  If E1 has a signed
>   type and nonnegative value, and E1× 2<sup>E2</sup> is representable in the result type, then that is
>   the resulting value; **otherwise, the behavior is undeﬁned**.

C++03 makes it undefined behaviour by [omitting the relevant text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3784996/why-does-left-shift-operation-invoke-undefined-behaviour-when-the-left-side-opera).

Comment: Either they wanted to test depth of knowledge, or they just plain don't know.  I've been to more than a few interviews where they didn't actually know the correct answer to a technical question.  More often than not, especially early stages, the interviewer is HR or management.  As I learned, the somewhat hard way, being highly proficient on the technical aspects doesn't help at all in becoming management...can even hurt your chances.  And HR...it's just not their area at all.  Trick questions like this are often asked by the least knowledgeable...in my experience.

Comment: @Noah: Yeah - I remember being told I was wrong about there being such a thing as a `signed char` type when I mentioned it in a response to being asked about the difference between `unsigned char` and plain-old `char`. But that was by a technical lead, not HR or management.

Comment: I'd need to check, but my understanding of the C standard was that shifting *by* a negative value was indeed undefined, but that shifting *a* negative value was "implementation-defined", i.e. it doesn't have to be the same on all platforms, but it needs to be defined. In any case, on any recent platform, -1<<4 better give -16 or else there's a lot of things that will break (starting with most media codecs).

Comment: @Jean-Marc: Prasoons' answer quotes directly from the C99 standard.  Left-shifting a negative value is undefined behavior.  However, if *right* shifting a negative value, the result is implementation defined.

Comment: Prasoon: litb's comment on your "omitting the relevant text" link leads me to think that there's ample room to interpret that snippet as meaning that left-shifting a negative integer is *implementation-defined*, rather than UB.  Just saying.

Answer (score 9):

No.  You're not correct.  That's the bad news.  Good news is that the interviewer probably doesn't know that and will assume you are because it's the result THEY get when they compile and run it.

True answer is that it is implementation defined.  I'm not 100% confident to say it IS undefined behavior because of the overload, but I think it may be.  At the very least though the result is dependent upon how negative numbers are represented, etc...  Neither language you've claimed this is in define what the output will be.

Comment: ...and I said that I thought it was.

Comment: "Because of the overload"?  Do you mean the "overloading" of tagging the question with `c` and `c++`?  If so: Could you possibly have chosen a more ambiguous term?  :-P

Answer (score 9):

On my machine:

```
chris@zack:~$ cat > test.c
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
       printf ("%x" ,-1<<4);
}

chris@zack:~$ gcc -o test test.c && ./test
fffffff0
```

However, the result will depend on your architecture and compiler.  So the correct answer is "it could output anything."

Comment: Compiler output is irrelevant.

Comment: Irrelevant, but interesting.  Nevertheless, there is nothing about my answer that is incorrect.

Comment: Not complaining about points (I'm capped anyway, I could care less) but when someone downvotes I usually expect them to leave feedback as to why, so that I have the opportunity to improve my answer.

Comment: I don't see how compiler output is irrelevant.  I would argue that it's more relevant than quoting the standard.  Especially when you get the same output for every compiler that anybody cares about.

Comment: So I gave you that feedback.  Quit complaining about it.

Comment: @PigBen compiler output is irrelevant because it is undefined behavior and the result may change for the next release of `<insert name of your favorite compiler here>`

Comment: @PigBen: Do you think "works today on my machine" is more relevant than the standard? Compiler output can be interesting but relying on UB can lead to software that's short-lived or fragile under maintenance.

Comment: @Praetorian: It may change, but you know as well as I that it won't, not unless int is extended to 64 bits.  And since the question is "What will the output be?" and not "What may the output be?", compiler output is a sensible answer.

Comment: @Blastfurnace: I would, of course, not rely on UB.  I would, of course, not write code like this.  But compilers do produce output for that code, so there is an answer.

Comment: @PigBen - and you just showed one very good reason why output is irrelevant and doesn't answer the question.  The question, at least as expressed by the OP, does not specify what compiler, version, architecture, etc so your assumption that it is NOT 64 bit (or 16 for that matter) is arbitrary and possibly completely wrong.

Comment: @PigBen - "But compilers do produce output for that code," is ultimately why I negged this particular answer.  It encourages this terribly flawed and erroneous pov.

Comment: @PigBen: Yes, compiler implementers are usually pretty nice about being backwards compatible when it comes to UB. In this particular case, the interviewer could've been looking for any one of a number of answers: 1. The answer given by the OP 2. Wanted the OP to recognize that it is UB. 3. Wanted to OP to state that the answer will change depending on the size of an int. In any case, a question that results in UB is a horrible one to ask at an interview.

Comment: Being practical here, the compiler output is relevant if only in that it suggests that the OP's answer has the highest probability of creating a good impression on the interviewer of any specific unqualified numeric answer (if we're generous enough to consider it implicit in cdhowie's use of GCC and lack of information to the contrary that he's probably on x86, which is so ubiquitous that an answer specific to that still has some value).  It's still worse than recognising it as undefined behaviour, but an interviewer who understood the entire situation would probably let it pass.

Answer (score 8):

```
Binary of 1  : 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 00001
```

Replace occurrence of 0 with 1 as you are going to calculate binary of negative no

[How to calculate binary of negative numbers](http://www.tutorvista.com/math/multiplying-binary-numbers)

```
Binary of -1 : 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 11111

Left shift 4 : 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 0000
```

Hex Representation of of resultant Left shift 4 
will be

```
1111 : F 

0000 : 0
```

so calculated output will be :

```
FFFFFFF0
```

Your answer is Right.

Comment: And who says the machine has to use twos complement?

Answer (score 3):

Left shifting a negative number is undefined for the *general* case but we have to understand why this undefined behavior (UB)?  Keep in mind that Most Significant Bit (MSb) is the sign bit.  If this bit is a 1 the number is negative.  If it is a zero the number is positive.  This is critical information is lost with the first left shift.  For example

```
-32768<<4
```

is the same thing as

```
0x8000<<4
```

(assuming a 16 bit machine for simplicity)

The result is, of course, 0 which doesn't really make any sense and is therefore UB.

In the specific case of the interview question from the OP, there is only one specific value we are concerned with...*not* the general case.  -1 (0xffffffff on a 32 bit machine) shifted left 4 times will yield 0xfffffff0 as the OP originally thought.

Comment: What you're describing is not undefined behavior, it's unspecified/implementation defined (depending on doc reqs).  Furthermore, -1 is not always '1111...111'.  It could be '1000...0001' or '111...1110'.  I'm still not completely convinced that -1 << X is undefined (the first sentence in 5.8/2 would seem to allow it), but we still can't say what the result is going to be without knowing what kind of negative number representation is being used and how large the type is.

Comment: If it is undefined, my guess as to reason is the possible involvement of overflow exceptions that's addition to the picture would mean the committee couldn't guarantee it to be even possible to let the program continue or how the OS would respond to such an event.  THAT is undefined behavior.

Comment: @Noah - I didn't realize -1 was represented by something other than '1111...111'.  Just out of curiosity, what kind (examples ?) of implementation does not use '1111...111' to represent -1?

Comment: @semaj: The C standard allows implementations using 2's complement, 1's complement and sign-magnitude representations.

Comment: @semaj: further nit-pick / even for 2's complement, "if [MSB] is a zero the number is positive" should say "non-negative".  Don't forget the number 0 has all bits 0 but is not positive.

Comment: It's impossible for the number to have all zero bits but not be positive. All zero bits is defined as zero for integer types. Furthermore, for unsigned values in the range of the corresponding signed type, the representations are identical, which is another reason zero must be zero.

Answer (score 1):

It's undefined behavior.

```
$ cat undef.c 
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
       printf ("%x" ,-1<<4); 
}
$ clang -fsanitize=undefined undef.c
$ ./a.out
undef.c:3:24: runtime error: left shift of negative value -1
fffffff0
```

Answer (score -1):

I ran this code on 3 different compilers and OS. All gave me this same answer as mentioned in the question. Until and unless someone came up with the compiler on which this is really undefined behavior, I will say the answer is RIGHT. If this is stable in 99.99% of the situations, then there are more chances of standard getting changed, than the compiler stop supporting it.

Comment: Well, on 16-bit DOS the answer is `fff0`.

Comment: Will BigEndian : LittleEndian CPU affect the answer as well?

Answer (score -4):

I just wrote the code in a text file, compiled it, and **YES**, the answer is correct.

Comment: @Akf: I understand. Thank you for your advice. It's been a long time since I worked with a compiled language and forgot all of this. I deserve the downvotes. Lesson learned u_u

Comment: +1 for a good attitude anyway :-).  Might as well delete the answer though...?  Same point's exhaustingly covered by cdhowie, who for no more reason than having cut-and-pasted his code, got 3 votes! @Alf: useful insight re Comeau's to share - thanks (interesting counter-example here though - as you'd know, even Comeau compiles/test-runs on *some* particular CPU, so it's shift behaviour here is no more authoratative than any other compilers / this is a case where undefined behaviour can be expected to be allowed to fall through to the CPU level rather than a Standards-compliance issue).