# What does it mean to return a value from a C program?

Tags: c

I'm very new to programming and confused about returning a value in the C language.

```
int main()
{
    printf("hallo world");
    return 0;
}
```

What does it mean to return the value `0` in the program?
Why should a main function return a value and to where does that return value go?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [Ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c++ - where does main() return its value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637671/where-does-main-return-its-value)

Answer (score 0):

let me tell you you are not good at asking questions. 
Here is the thing.I beleve and i am guessing that you are too new to programmings. So here is the basic. In c functions are in this form

```
 <return type> <function name> (<parameter1,....>){
    <function body>
   }
```

So as you have asked that what does it mean by returning a value. well if you define a  you have to return something in that for. otherwise if you define it as `void` you do not need to.

basically returning something from a function is the ultimate key to programming. that is how the flow goes on. When you use some function (given that you have defined the return type) you assign the returned value like this

example

```
int add(int a, int b)
{

    printf("%d",a+b);
    return a+b;
}
```

now that
you call the function like this in the main function

```
c = add(4,5);
```

and the return value iss assigned to c

hope this was what you were asking

Comment: Thank you so much. I know I need to work on myself, thank you for your feedback also

Answer (score 0):

> What does it mean to return the value 0 in the program?

**ISO/IEC 9899:201x** / **Environment** / … / **Hosted environment** / **Program termination**:

> If the return type of the `main` function is a type compatible with `int`,
>   a return from the initial call to the `main` function is equivalent to
>   calling the `exit` function with the value returned by the `main` function
>   as its argument…

**ISO/IEC 9899:201x** / **Library** / … / **Communication with the environment** / **The `exit` function**:

> Finally, control is returned to the host environment. If the value of
>   `status` is zero or `EXIT_SUCCESS`, an implementation-defined form of the
>   status *successful termination* is returned. If the value of `status` is
>   `EXIT_FAILURE`, an implementation-defined form of the status
>   *unsuccessful termination* is returned…

---

> Why should a main function return a value and to where does that
>   return value go?

A `main` function and thereby a program should return a value going to the caller to inform it about the success of the execution, e. g. in a UNIX environment to allow a calling shell script to test for the program's success or failure and take appropriate action:

```
if program
then echo okay
else exit 1
fi
```